# What's the most efficient way to pull culture information out of a resx's filename in c#?

Tags: c#, string

What's the most efficient way to pull culture information out of a resx's filename using C#?  The solution should also handle there not being culture info in the file name (ie form1.resx).  In that case a string assigned "Default" should be returned.

Comment: Are you trying to pull it out during the request? Or is this just a simple string manipulation (as the tag indicates)?

Comment: I should add that I won't know which culture is contained between the periods.  Basically if one is there then I need to grab it, else return "Default".

Comment: aronchick - Just string manipulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like it would work:

```
string GetCulture(string s)
{
  var arr=s.Split(".");
  if(arr.Length>2)
    return arr[1];
  else
    return "Default";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is just using regex:

```
string ParseCulture(string input)
{
  var r = Regex.new('[\w\d]+\.([\w\-]+)\.resx')
  // Match the regular expression pattern against a text string.
  Match m = r.Match(input);
  if (m.Success)
  {
     return m.Groups[1];
  }
  else
  {
     return "Default";
  }
}
```

This gets back a match (with the phrase you're looking for as the match), or no match (which means you should use "Default").

Comment: Sorry, I asked the question poorly.  I don't know exactly which culture will be there, I just need to grab it if it is between the periods.